# FFmpeg: How to decrease the volume for few seconds in the middle of audio file multiple time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an audio file with 24 seconds duration. I want to make the volume muted from 5th second to 7th second and 9th th to 15th second  using FFmpeg in single execution.

`ffmpeg -y -i input.wav -filter_complex "[0]volume=0:enable='between(t,9,15)':'between(t,5,7)'" output.wav`

`ffmpeg -y -i input.wav -af volume=0:enable='between(t,9,15)' -af volume=0:enable='between(t,5,7)' out.wav`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,7)':volume=0, volume=enable='between(t,9,15)':volume=0" output.wav
```

This should define a audio filter `-af` for volume that will be enabled `volume=enable` between the specified time `='between(t,5,7)'` and set the volume to 0 `:volume=0` . 
You can add multiple statements seperated with comma to have multiple sections filtered/muted.

Comment: No need for two filters: `volume=0:enable='between(t,5,7)+between(t,9,15)'`